# How to create mybatis mapper on demand with spring 4.2.3?

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have a demon process that will keep looping,when a specific time point meet in every day,it will do something by invoking a method in a mapper,the problem is that after several minutes,I will get:

Data source is closed

It seems that mapper will expire after a while,and I need to create mapper on-demand when trigger condition (specific time point) satisfied.I have found this:
  http://zezutom.blogspot.jp/2014/01/spring-series-part-4-lazy-on-injection.html
but it doesn't work as expectation,so question is

```
how do create mybatis mapper on demand?
```

Comment: Perhaps you can pose the exception for the rest to help out ?

Comment: Do you mean to catch the exception,if occurred,recreate mapper?If so,how to recreate mapper on demand?

Comment: You don't need to create mapper on demand. You need to figure out why your `Data source is closed`. How is `DataSource` configured in your project?